React 19's new form action function doesn't append file object to its formData parameter object
I am building an app with nextjs 15 where react 19 has been incorporated. So, I wanted to use the new formAction way in form which is basically you put a function like ''. I have also added shadcn form in it.
Now, the problem I am facing is formAction function is having all the fields except image file. So, my question is why it is not being included in the formData parameter of the formAction and how to make it work as a formData element/property ?
It actually includes the file to the field value but isn't found in the formData object.
By the way, I found out that it works just fine with react-hook-form's onSubmit method onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
here is how the form component looks like:
const formSchema = z
  .object({
    ...,
    picture: z
      .custom<File>((file) => file instanceof File, {
        message: "Invalid file type.",
      })
      .refine(
        (file) =>
          ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/webp"].includes(
            file.type
          ),
        {
          message:
            "Invalid image type. Only PNG, JPEG, JPG, and WEBP are allowed.",
        }
      )
      .refine((file) => file.size <= 5 * 1024 * 1024, {
        message: "Image size must not exceed 5MB.",
      }),
    ...
  })

const RegisterForm: React.FC<RegisterFormProps> = () => {
  // 1. Define your form.
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      username: "",
      email: "",
      picture: undefined,
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
    },
  })

  function formAction(formData: FormData) {
    console.log(formData.get("picture"))
    console.log(formData.get("name"))
  }

  return (
    ...
    <Form {...form}>
      <form action={formAction}>
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="picture"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormControl>
                <Input
                  type="file"
                  accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/webp" // Accept only valid image formats
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    if (e.target.files) {
                      const file = e.target.files[0] // Get the first file from the file input
                      field.onChange(file) // Pass the `File` object to the form field
                    }
                  }}
                />
              </FormControl>
            </FormItem>
        />
        ...
        ...
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  )

